# To upload Videos to youtube from Ruby on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video, youtube, youtube-api

I am developing an app, which needs to upload videos to youtube. I have got client_id , api_key and client_secret_key from [console.developers.google.com](https://console.developers.google.com). I have also used [omniauth_googleoauth2](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2) for successful authentication and stored user details in database. Now, how to insert/upload an video to youtube. I have tried [yt gem](https://github.com/Fullscreen/yt) , but current version don't have an function like " insert.video ". I have also went through [google_api_client](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert). But don't know to proceed. Is there any solutions for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems yt gem [has](https://github.com/Fullscreen/yt/blob/c153ab0037a4ecd86926027fba3c1093a70d7e13/lib/yt/models/account.rb#L62-L78) upload support. Here is a full documentation for it: https://fullscreen.github.io/yt/accounts.html

Short summary from the link above:

```
Yt.configuration.client_id = "<your ID>"
Yt.configuration.client_secret = "<your secret>"
account = Yt::Account.new refresh_token: "<token>"

account.upload_video "http://example.com/remote_video.mp4", title: 'My video'
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution!

Comment: @ThananjayaS while doing this task(upload video to youtube), did you face any video upload quota(limit) issue?

Comment: No @AfzalMasood

Comment: @nattfodd did you face any video upload quota(limit) issue? or limitation that the app can only post a limited number of videos